# Django + Webpack + Vue + Code splitting - How to change load url of chunk files

Tags: javascript, django, webpack, vue.js, code-splitting

I am using Django with Webpack and Vue, And Code splitting in Webpack. Webpack split chunk files from source code of .vue files. But, I can't load chunk files on Web browser because url is incorrect in my project structure. I want to change load url of chunk files but I don't know these. How to change load url of chunk files?

Chrome console logs:

```
GET http://localhost:8123/mycomponent.chunk.js 404 (Not Found)
main.js:12 Error: Loading chunk 2 failed.
(error: http://localhost:8123/mycomponent.chunk.js)
    at HTMLScriptElement.a (main.js:1)
```

I need url of '/static/js/mycomponent.chunk.js'.

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require('webpack')
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
context: __dirname,

entry: './src/main.js',

output: {
    path: path.resolve('../static/js/'),
    filename: "[name].js",
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
},

module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
    },
    ],
},

plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
],

resolve: {
    alias: {
    'vue': path.resolve('./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js'),
    }
},
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `publicPath: '/static/js/'` to output.

Also, if you serve your js from your Django template page, you can use django-webpack-loader, it simplifies serving js files and supports hot module reloading.